# How to set current user to be an attribute of the ModelForm?

Tags: python, django, django-forms

I have a form which creates a `Reservation` object. This object has a `customer = models.ForeignKey(User)` - which is a required attribute.

What to do to be able to create object using `ReservationCreationForm().save()`?

I've tried to overwrite save method:

```
def save(self,user,*args,**kwargs):
    self.customer = user
    super(ReservationCreationForm).save()
```

so I could create a form with `request.user` attribute but it not works - Exception Value:

```
'super' object has no attribute 'save'
```

What would you do?

**EDIT**

According to todor's answer, I've changed the save to

```
def save(self,user,*args,**kwargs):
    self.customer = user 
    super(ReservationCreationForm, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
```

Which solved problem with save() itself but it still does not add `user` to the `Reservation` so it raises Exception Value:

```
va_app_reservation.customer_id may not be NULL
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your are not calling the `.save` method correctly. `super` accepts a second argument which is the object instance.

```
super(ReservationCreationForm, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
```

UPDATE

You are not setting `customer` to a `reservation instance`, but to a `form instance`, that's why your `reservation` object does not have a `customer`.

try with this one, (and don't forget the `return`):

```
def save(self, user, *args,**kwargs):
    self.instance.customer = user 
    return super(ReservationCreationForm, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
```

Comment: Thanks but it still doesn't add user to the Reservation... customer is defined in model, I didn't define it anywhere in ModelForm except save() method.

Comment: @MilanoSlesarik i've updated my answer, give it a try now.